# When using boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_post to generate an URL for a file upload via form submit an error from AWS occurs

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, python-3.7, amazon-iam

As mentioned in this question's title, when using the boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_post to generate an upload URL as per [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post) and injecting the response of the function into the following form:

```
 <form class="s3-upload" action="URL_VALUE" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="VALUE"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="VALUE"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="VALUE"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="VALUE"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="VALUE"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="upload-input">
    <p class="drag-text">Drag your file here or click in this area.</p>
    <button id="uploadS3" type="submit" title="">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

I receive the following error from AWS: **The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.**

The application runs inside a docker on AWS Fargate and has an AWS role attached to it. This must probably have something to do with the solution because the whole functionality works fine on my local machine. Furthermore, all other AWS related operations with S3 (also with SQS) work fine with that AWS Fargate/AWS role setting. I'm looking forward to any suggestions about what to do.